# Selecting a single row is Selecting all other rows in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am calculating estimated cost. Selecting a product fetch the details about the product and showing it's description and price on the input box. And then upon clicking in add button a new row will appear for another selection. But the problem is the new row appears with the older row data. And changing a single row affects all other rows. Here is my code so far:

```
<tbody v-for="row in rows" :key="index">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select @change="selected" v-model="product_id" class="form-control" name="product_id" id="product_id">
                <option value="">Select Product</option>
                <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.id" v-text="item.product_name"></option>
            </select>                                           
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea type="text" v-model="product.product_details" name="product_details" id="product_details" class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="Product Details"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input v-model.number="product.product_sellPrice" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="rate" id="rate" placeholder="Rate">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input v-model.number="product.product_tax" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="tax" id="tax" placeholder="Tax">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input v-model="quantity" type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
        </td>
            
        <td> 
            <input :value="total" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" placeholder="Total Price">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" v-on:click="addrow" >
                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <button v-show="length > 1" class="btn btn-secondary" @click.prevent="removerow(index)">
                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```

Vue Part

```
<script>
    export default{
        props: ['products'],

        data() {

            return {
                rows: [{

                }],
            
                items: this.products,
                product: '',
                product_id: '',
                quantity: '',
                index: '',
                total_price: '',
            }
        },
            

        methods: {
            addrow: function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.rows.push({
                });
            },

            removerow: function (index) {
                this.rows.splice(index, 1);
            },

            selected(e){
                var id = this.product_id;
                console.log(id);
                axios.get('/estimate/product/' + id)
                  .then((response)=>{
                        this.product = '';
                        this.product = response.data;
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                  }); 
            },  
        }
    }
</script>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a single part of my project. But I think It has no other connection without fetching the data from database with the project. Here is my complete code for this part and I think I am doing wrong in selecting rows

Comment: Get running code working in jsfiddle.net and post here, it will be easier to help you.. How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It will not work in JSFiddle. But I have made the code shorter.

Comment: By creating a bare minimum example can help the troubleshooting, code does not have to reflect your actual service. I do think one problem is that when you add a new row completely empty, add the new row with parameters defined but empty, something like this: this.rows.push({'Param1':''});

Answer (score 1):

`key` should be a unique identifier for each row. You have `index` defined in the `data` object and you use it for all the rows as key, that causes problems.

Also it is not recommended to use the row index as a key since it changes when you add/remove rows.

So you need to add some identifier to each row item and use it as the key, here is a simple example of how to do it:

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(index,item) in inventory" :key="item.name">
      {{ item.name }} - ${{ item.price }}
      <button @click="add">Add</button>
      <button @click="remove(index)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>


</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    counter: 1,
    inventory: [{
      name: 'MacBook Air',
      price: 1000
    }, {
      name: 'MacBook Pro',
      price: 1800
    }, {
      name: 'Lenovo W530',
      price: 1400
    }, {
      name: 'Acer Aspire One',
      price: 300
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.inventory.push({
        name: 'item' + this.counter++,
        price: this.counter * 1000
      })
    },
    remove: function(index) {
      this.inventory.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1rancd5g/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know the way you have done it. But the thing is I have select option and upon selecting an item I am sending an axios request to get the property of the item. 
i

Comment: The new code is like this from your suggestion:
https://jsfiddle.net/5phq111c/2/
But the problem remains all the same. Where is the problem in the code?

Comment: The new code you posted has the same problem, you are using for the key `row.id`, but row has no id. add an id property to the row. You can look here for how to generate an id: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: Can I use the row.product_id as the key? And I have bind the product_id with row and sending axios request by product id to get the value. But this is not working. I am getting error 404. How can I catch the id and send the request? The fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/5phq111c/4/

Comment: you can bind anything that is unique, regarding the 404, it means the server does not know the url you are calling

Comment: Yeah the id of the url is missing. So how can I use the row.product_id as the id of the url in axios request? If I use var id = this.row.product_id and the url is ('/estimate/product/' + id) , this is giving me the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'product_id' of undefined.